# unable to use blur effect correctly in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am trying to create a login page.

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ClipLoader } from "react-spinners";
import "./style.css";

function Login() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  //var [toggle, setToggle] = useState(0.3);

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  

  const makeBlur1 = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    setDisabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div class= {loading ? 'blur' : 'container'}>
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={makeBlur1} disabled={disabled}>
          login
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <div
          id="loadingDiv"
          class="box stack-top"
          style={{ background: "white", border: "2px solid black" }}
        >
          <ClipLoader /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <span
            id="loadingDivText"
            style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}
          >
            Loading...
          </span>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

//end
```

css

```
body{
    background: black;
}

.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;            
    position: absolute;
    
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;  /* for demo purpose  */

    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.stack-top{
    z-index: 9;
    margin: -20px -20px -20px -80px; /* for demo purpose  */
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.blur{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    filter: blur(2px);
  }
```

what i want is when i click on login button the background to get blurred and display me the `loadingDiv`. but on button click the whole screen gets blurred. can someone help?

i have tried using opacity toggle as well but i keep on getting error `unable to setProperty of null` while i try and use

```
document.getElementById("loadingDiv")[0].style.opacity = 1
```

--------------edit

login.js

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ClipLoader } from "react-spinners";
import "./style.css";

function Login() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  //var [toggle, setToggle] = useState(0.3);

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const makeBlur1 = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    setDisabled(true);

  };

  return (
    <div>

{loading ? (
          <div
            class="box stack-top"
            style={{ background: "white", border: "2px solid black" }}
          >
            <ClipLoader /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <span
              style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}
            >
              Loading...
            </span>
          </div>
        ) : null}


      <div class={loading ? "blur" : "container"}>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="password" />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <button onClick={makeBlur1} disabled={disabled}>
            login
          </button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

//end
```

style.css

```
body{
    background: black;
}

.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;            
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    justify-self: center;
    opacity: 0.8;  /* for demo purpose  */

    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.stack-top{
    z-index: 9;
    margin: -20px -20px -20px -80px; /* for demo purpose  */
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.blur{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    filter: blur(2px);
  }
```

now the blur effect is working fine but the div is not center aligned. it is left aligned. how do i fix that?

Comment: Your loader is a child of the element that you blur - of course, it will be blurred. Blur the div that isn't a parent of that loader instead.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski as per you suggestions i have made changes. can you check edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed this issue.

App.js

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./login/login";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Loader from "./loader/loader";

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);



  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const makeBlur1 = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    setDisabled(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!loading ? (
        <Login loading={loading} disabled={disabled} makeBlur1={makeBlur1} />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div style={{marginLeft: "480px"}}><Loader /></div>
          <Login loading={loading} disabled={disabled} makeBlur1={makeBlur1} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

login.js

```
import React from "react";
import Loader from "../loader/loader";
import "./style.css";

function Login(props) {
  
  return (
    <div>

{/* {loading ? (
          <Loader />
        ) : null} */}


      <div class={props.loading ? "blur" : "container"}>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="password" />
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <button onClick={props.makeBlur1} disabled={props.disabled}>
            login
          </button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

//end
```

style.css

```
//for login

body{
    background: black;
}

.container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;            
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    justify-self: center;
    opacity: 0.8;  /* for demo purpose  */

    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.stack-top{
    z-index: 9;
    margin: -20px -20px -20px -80px; /* for demo purpose  */
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.blur{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    filter: blur(2px);
  }
```

loader.js

```
import React from "react";
import { ClipLoader } from "react-spinners";
import "./style.css";

function Loader() {
  return (
    <div
      class="box stack-top"
      style={{ background: "white", border: "2px solid black" }}
    >
      <ClipLoader /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "30px" }}>Loading...</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Loader;

//end
```

style.css

```
//for loader

body{
    background: black;
}

.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;            
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    justify-self: center;
    opacity: 0.8;  /* for demo purpose  */

    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.stack-top{
    z-index: 9;
    margin: -20px -20px -20px -80px; /* for demo purpose  */
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

now when you click on login button it will blur background and show the loader div.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, or you don't need something very customizable, you can use this package:

[react-spinner-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay)

the only piece of code you need to add in App.js is

```
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const logOut = async (evt) => {
        setLoading(true);
        evt.preventDefault();
        dispatch(logout(user.token))
          .then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      };

  return (
 <RingSpinnerOverlay loading={loading}  overlayColor="rgba(0,153,255,0.2)" color="#0275d8" borderWidth = "4"
  />

      <div className="App">
...
</div>
```